# Which Stack Exchange site would be appropriate for questions about file naming conventions, and extensions for common file types?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

For example, the variety of extensions used on plaintext files to indicate their purpose, such as .nfo for information files, .me for read.me files etc.

I think probably Stack Overflow or Super User, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 11):

Super User is the site you should ask it, since it is a question about software and  computers.

Stack Overflow is for programming questions only, so that wouldn't be a good idea.

Per the comment:

Ask Different or Unix and Linux are also possible when dealing with OS specific files.

Comment: Also be aware of sites such as Ask Different or Unix and Linux when dealing with OS specific files