# Better Way To Decide Which Stack Exchange Is Appropriate For Question

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I want to ask following question:

> How to boot [Ninja Developer Platform](http://dap.xeonphi.com/#platformspecs) kernel via NFS without erasing the original on board kernel?

This is equally suited for best for *Stack Overflow*, *Server Fault*, *Super User*, *Unix & Linux* and *Network Engineering*.

For such scenario, how does one make a decision on which Stack Exchange is better suited?

Advantage of *Stack Overflow* is that it will receive faster response due to user base, and also majority of technical question qualify automatically for *Stack Overflow* rather than a specific site like *Unix & Linux*.

I am also sure, majority of new user will directly go ahead and put such question on *Stack Overflow*, thus making specific sites redundant.

Please suggest how you tackle such scenario, thank you.

Comment: I don't see enough programming related stuff in it that it would fly on SO. Super User or U&L seems a better fit. Try a chatroom to work out which site want it.

Comment: Failing to understand the reasons behind `downvotes` (just asking, not here for `reputations` etc.). As something similar asked [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/261663/which-stack-exchange-site-would-be-appropriate-for-questions-about-file-naming-c?rq=1) was received well. And, obviously I will articulate my question whereever I post it on `Stack Exchange`. Thought, having similar question details on multiple places won't be a good idea.

Comment: Because your question is much more vague then the one you linked to. Also your title hints on a opinion based questions, the body seems to request a site-recommendation but in the end veers of to some sort of general advice. The other question **IS** a site-recommendation, yours tries to be one but failed. And that is also visible by the current answer, or as someone said *asking where to ask where to ask*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you would ask here under the tag [site-recommendation](/questions/tagged/site-recommendation), which you already have...

You would use that tag though it is more practical to write out your whole post or at least fill in specific details that may be helpful in the site choice. As the tag wiki says:

> After looking through the site list, https://stackexchange.com/sites, you don't know where to ask your question on the Stack Exchange Network? Give as much detail as possible about the question you'd like to ask, and the community will help you find the appropriate site.

Your question itself *seems* like it might fit all those communities but the details that go with it should be the deciding factor. Thus, ask another question with [site-recommendation](/questions/tagged/site-recommendation) and probably [support](/questions/tagged/support), add in your proposed question with details, and you should get a relatively accurate answer.

Comment: .@AnthonyPham - Agreed. But, (_add in your proposed question with details_) does it make sense to have question with similar details on `meta` and on another `Stack Exchange` (SE) site? Usually, on SE we avoid duplication? Or, it's that moderators will move it to appropriate site from `meta`?